# How to search for combining (non-spacing) characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode

In a MySQL database of ancient Greek words, I want to look for all words which have a character with a dot underneath the letter (Unicode Character 'COMBINING DOT BELOW' (U+0323)) and remove this.

I tried various encodings, but none seems to work ...

Comment: Collation is utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you have a column `col` in table `t`, and `col` is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

```
SELECT ...
    FROM t
    WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)*CCA3'
```

Will locate all lines with `U+0323` (encoded as UTF-8 `CCA3`).

Alas, there is no easy way to modify `col` in SQL.

If you have MariaDB, then `UNHEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(HEX(col), 'CCA3', ''))` will almost work.  The problem is that it could be misaligned (at an odd boundary).

Another thought:  `REPLACE(col, UNHEX('CCA3'), '')` might work in MySQL or MariaDB.  However, it could get into issues with Collations.  So, perhaps this would work:  `REPLACE(col COLLATE utf8_bin, UNHEX('CCA3'), '')`

Comment: Thanks, searching worked perfectly, and that was the main thing.